# Performing mass file renaming on the Lightroom database

Tags: adobe, lightroom

I'd like to perform a mass renaming of all files in the lightroom database
From: xxx_2.nef
To  : xxx.nef

I.e, for each image, if the name contains _2, then remove it.

Which tables and columns would be appropriate to hit?

Comment: StackOverflow is not where to ask support questions about Adobe Lightroom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using sql lite to open up the .lrcat file: Ran this query to fix the issue:

```
update AgLibraryFile
set basename = substr(basename, 0, length(basename) -1),
idx_filename = substr(basename, 0, length(basename) -1)  || '.' || extension,
lc_idx_filename = substr(basename, 0, length(basename) -1)  || '.' || extension,
originalFileName = substr(basename, 0, length(basename) -1)  || '.' || extension
WHERE basename like '%-2'
```